# how to check if a specific array key is exist in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, laravel-5

if i'm accessing an index like that

```
$var = $final_Length_Array[1][0]['id'];
```

how to check whether the "id" key index exist in the array or not.

i tried to use function `array_key_exists` but it seems to be working only on one dimension array.

i tried it like `if(array_key_exists('id',$final_Length_Array)){` but it didn't work

i also tried isset to check whether there is a result or not but it didn't work also `if(isset($final_Length_Array[1][0]['id'])){`

any help i'll be appreciate it

Comment: Please give an example array that gives you the problem.

Comment: the array is like 
`[
      {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "year": "1st",
        "curriculum": "Arts"
      }
    ]`

Comment: Then you don't have `[1]`.

Comment: actually the complete array is `"list",
    [
      {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "year": "1st",
        "curriculum": "Arts"
      }
    ]`

so "1" means the first array in list

Comment: With that data you last attempt (with `isset`) works. I cannot reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Super hacky solution:

```
function array_key_exists_recursive($array, $key) {
    return strpos(json_encode($array), "\"" . $key . "\":") !== false;
}
```

Better solution:

```
$array = ['a' => ['b' => 'c']];
function array_key_exists_recursive($key, $array) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
        return true;
    }
    foreach($array as $k => $value) {
        if (is_array($value) && array_key_exists_recursive($key, $value)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;            
}

var_dump(array_key_exists_recursive('b', $array));
```

Comment: super cool , it works fine and now i can retrieve any index .
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```php
$var = $final_Length_Array[1][0]['id'] ?? false;
```

returns the value of `id` or `false`